# SQL query from 2 table into one (is this done by using join?)

Tags: sql, join

I have a table called products, products has several fields, 2 of those are of importance in this question, column ID and column ProdDetail.

I have another table lets call it table2. Table2 has an ID column and a Name column.

I want to run an sql query which does the following:

```
insert into table3  products.ID and table2.ID 
where products.ProdDetail CONTAINS table2.Name
```

I know that this code isn't valid sql statement. Also I can't use join because products.ProdDetail contains more data than just table2.name, so they are not exactly the same.

Comment: You probably should correct your data if you have a field with a bunch of different data elements in it

Comment: I didn't quite understand your question, but you can use LIKE in your JOIN condition, e.g. `ON products.ProdDetail LIKE CONCAT('%', table2.name, '%')`

Comment: @JNK Based on your reputation im assuming that you have dealt with a situation when you had to overtake somebody else's - probably-less-than-great - data structure before , also what you suggest is what im trying to do at the moment :) effieciently

Comment: @shesek Didnt thought of that! will try out and report back, seems what im looking for

Comment: @andris - be advised a `LIKE` join condition of the type that you need will force at least one, probably two table scans.  Not pretty.

Comment: @JNK can you propose another answer? i mean the question has 4 answers already, but all of those are done with LIKE joins

Comment: @Andris - nope, that's the only way to do this.  That's why I said fix the structure :)  Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean something like this?

```
INSERT  INTO table3 ( ProductID, Table2ID )
        SELECT  product.Id,
                table2.ID
        FROM    products
                INNER JOIN table2 ON products.ProdDetail LIKE CONCAT('%', table2.name, '%')
```

Comment: @Andris, I'm confused, you say table3 has two fields, `id` and `name`, yet you want to insert two id's into those fields??

Comment: @Johan you're confused because you probably misread the question, i never said anything about table3's fields, table2 has the id and name fields :) read it again, :)

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO table3 (id, name)
SELECT
  p.id as ID
  , p.productDetail as name
FROM products p 
INNER JOIN table2 t2 ON (t2.id = p.id) 
      AND (p.productdetail LIKE CONCAT('%',t2.name,'%')
```

Comment: this is a correct one also with COALESCE, which is probably for filtering out NULL valued rows, right?

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO
  table3
SELECT
  products.ID,
  table2.ID
FROM
  products
INNER JOIN
  table2
    ON products.ProdDetail LIKE '%' + table2.Name + '%'
```

Comment: are you sure this syntax is allowed? `'%' + table2.Name + '%'` IIRC, CONCAT is required.

Comment: It depends on the version of SQL.  I have seen `+`, `|` and `&` used, as well as the more verbose `CONCAT()` function.

Answer (score 1):

I *think* that this is what you want:

```
INSERT INTO Table3 (prod_id, table2_id)
SELECT
    P.id,
    T2.id
FROM
    Products P
INNER JOIN Table2 T2 ON
    P.ProdDetail LIKE '%' + T2.name + '%'
```

Just keep in mind that if you have any table 2 names that are substrings of another name that you're going to get duplicate/erroneous data. For example, if you have Table2 names of "widgets" and "foobar widgets" and you have a Product description of "These are foobar widgets" then it's going to relate both Table2 rows to the Product row.

Comment: I know, this is what i want :) the 3rd table will help me create a many-to-many association between two tables